# Filtrar información en base a campos relacionados django

Tags: django, busqueda, modelos, filtros-css

Estimado(as). Espero me puedan ayudar.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación y tengo varios modelos:

El modelo Procesos:

```
    class Proceso(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    # resolucion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objeto = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    tipos = {
        ('01', 'Constructor'),
        ('02', 'Fiscalizador'),
        ('03', 'Administrador de contrato'),
    }
    tipo_contratacion = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=tipos, default='01')
    forma_pago = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    plazo_entrega = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Plazo de entrega (meses)')
    Fecha_publica = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha de publicación')
    estados = {
        ('01', 'En Trámite'),
        ('02', 'Adjudicado'),
        ('03', 'Fallido')
    }
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=estados, default='01')
    Fecha_propuesta = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha de entrega de las propuestas')
    Fecha_adjudica = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha estimada de adjudicación')
    relacion_proyectos = models.ForeignKey(Proyectos, null=True, verbose_name='Proyecto', 
    blank=True,
                                           on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    relacion_usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, verbose_name='Encargado', blank=True,
                                         on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    monto_experiencia = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)

    personas_p = [
        ('01', 'Natural'),
        ('02', 'Jurídica')
    ]
    dirigido = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=personas_p, default='01', 
   verbose_name='Dirigido a')

    def __str__(self):
        txt = "{0}"
        return txt.format(self.codigo)
```

El modelo Usuario

```
    class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    areas = [ # para filtrar
        ('01', 'Constructor'),
        ('02', 'Fiscalizador'),
        ('03', 'Administrador de contrato')
    ]
    area_aplica = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=areas, default='02', help_text="Escoja el 
    área")
    personas = [ # para filtrar
        ('01', 'Natural'),
        ('02', 'Jurídica')
    ]
    tipo = [ # para establecer permisos de usuario

        ('01', 'Oferente'),
        ('02', 'Técnico'),
        ('03', 'Administrador')
    ]
    tipo_persona = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=personas, default='01')
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Cedula', unique=True)
    ruc = models.CharField(max_length=13, verbose_name='RUC', unique=True)
    experiencia = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    tipo_usuario = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=tipo, default='01')
    tel_cel = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Telf. Celular')
    tel_con = models.CharField(max_length=7, verbose_name='Telf. Convencional')
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Dirección', blank=True)

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self, exclude=['last_login'])
        item['full_name'] = self.get_full_name()
        item['date_joined'] = self.date_joined.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        item[
            'value'] = f'{self.get_full_name()} Tipo: ({self.get_tipo_usuario_display()}) Area: 
    ({self.get_area_aplica_display()})'

        item['experiencia'] = format(self.experiencia, '.2f')
        return item
```

El modelo Invitaciones

```
class Invitaciones(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID Invitación')
fecha_crea_invita = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
relacion_usuarioi = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, verbose_name='Encargado', 
blank=False,
                                      on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name='invita')
relacion_procesoi = models.ForeignKey(Proceso, null=True, verbose_name='Proceso', blank=False,
                                      on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
fecha_invitacion = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.now, 
verbose_name='Fecha')

def user_email(self):
    return self.relacion_usuarioi.email

def fecha_propuesta(self):
    return self.relacion_procesoi.Fecha_propuesta

def __str__(self):
    txt = "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}"
    return txt.format('ID:', self.id, ' / Proceso: ', self.relacion_procesoi, '/ Encargado:',
                      self.relacion_usuarioi, '/ Correo: ', self.relacion_usuarioi.email)

class Meta:
    ordering = ["id"]
    verbose_name = "Invitación"
    verbose_name_plural = "Invitaciones"
```

```
Y el modelo Invitados

    class Invitados(models.Model):
    invitaciones = models.ForeignKey(Invitaciones, db_column='invitaciones_id', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rela_invitaciones')
    invitado = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, db_column='id_user', on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    estados1 = {
        ('01', 'Adjudicado'),
        ('02', 'Invitado')
    }
    estado_invitado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=estados1, default='02')

    def __str__(self):
        txt = "{0}"
        return txt.format(self.invitado)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["invitado"]
        verbose_name = "Invitado"
        verbose_name_plural = "Invitados"
```

El modelo procesos está relacionado con el modelo de invitaciones, y el de invitaciones está relacionado con el modelo de Invitados. El modelo de Invitados está relacionado con el de Usuarios.
El modelo Procesos tiene todos los campos por los que se debe filtrar, estos son:
•   tipo_contratacion
•   dirigido
•   monto_experiencia

Necesito filtrar la información de la tabla de usuarios tomando en cuenta los tres filtros de la tabla procesos y cargarlos en la tabla de invitados.

Cuando presione el botón  buscar invitados se debe cargar la lista con los datos obtenidos de los tres filtros.
[image: Vista]

Comment: ¿Ya tienes implementada una versión básica para el filtrado, puedes compartir como lo estas haciendo para guiarte? ¿Que utilizas para cargar tu invitados en el frontend (Datatables, tablas normales, etc)?

Comment: Hola Kevin. ¿Ya tienes implementada una versión básica para el filtrado. No Todavía -----, puedes compartir como lo estas haciendo para guiarte? Claro.  ¿Que utilizas para cargar tu invitados en el frontend (Datatables, tablas normales, etc)? estoy utilizando Datatables